# What should be the correct Fibonacci sequence, where I am doing wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, fibonacci

Here is my python code for sequence of 'Fibonacci Numbers '. My code counts the Fibonacci sequence as  (0,1,1,2,3........ ). But what I can see at many places Fibonacci sequence as ( 0,1,2,3,5.....).

My code generates ' 1 ' as the output for input ' 3 '. But when I am submitting it to Coursera, they expect the output of ' 2 ' for input ' 3 '.

Here is my code, please tell me where I am doing wrong.

```
N = int(input())

#initialize the list with starting elements: 0, 1
fibonacciSeries = [0,1]

if (N>=0 and N<=1):
    print(fibonacciSeries[N])
    

else:
    for i in range(2, N):
        #next elment in series = sum of its previous two numbers
        nextElement = fibonacciSeries[i-1] + fibonacciSeries[i-2]
       
        #append the element to the series
        fibonacciSeries.append(nextElement)
    
    print(fibonacciSeries[-1])
```

Comment: fibonacciSeries = [1,1] to adhere to courseras expectations

Answer (score 1):

The Fibonacci sequence is often stated to begin with `1, 1`, not `0, 1` (though `0, 1` is also a common start point). To match the site's expectations, either make your initial `list` `[1, 1]` or run your `range` out to `N + 1`, not `N`.